# Grab variable from clicked anchor tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I'm currently working on producing a basic content management system. In this code I'm grabbing a list of pages from the database 'posts' and then echoing them out. The purpose of the list is for users to be able to select an existing page and then edit the title & content, however I'm unsure on how I can take data from the selected link and then make my page-edit.php show the correct content to edit accordingly. I've assigned the variable $i to each of the anchor tags which increments throughout the while loop, ideally I'd use $i to SELECT the correct page from the database. I'd like to avoid using jQuery, although I'm assuming that's going to be suggested. Any insight would be great, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
        mysql_select_db('posts');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM pages";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $i++;
            echo '<a href="edit-page.php">' . $row['page_title'] . ' - ' . $i . '</a>' . '</br>';
        }
        mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Why not use it as a GET variable in the anchor tag: `echo '<a href="edit-page.php?id=' . $i . '>` ?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding so promptly! Could you give me some further insight into how I would go about doing this?

Comment: @Egg makes a good suggestion! Also Leon, are you sure you want to create your own CMS? I see no real reason to do this (unless it's a training exercise).

Comment: On page-edit.php would I grab the id ($i) from the page URL?

Comment: @MatthewLymer It's by far the best idea I've seen after searching Stack and other sites. I know Wordpress and other CMS' are extremely flexible and can't be beaten due to the size of their development teams, but I'm mainly doing this to improve my knowledge of PHP and SQL. Also I'd quite like to have a white label CMS to use with small client projects.

Comment: You'd have to integrate the whole `get` request param on the edit page side doing that, this question cannot really have a straight forwards answer. a) you integrate a request module to your CMS or b) you make an edit page for each page and go to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$i` as a GET `id` variable in the link within the while loop:

`echo '<a href="edit-page.php?id=' . $i . '>' . $row['page_title'] . ' - ' . $i . '</a>' . '</br>';`

Then you can check for `$_GET['id']` so that you know what id/page is to be edited and get the data for that from the database:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id=' . $_GET['id'];
  ...
  // Show the form populated with data from the above query.
}
```

I've kept this very simple to get you started.

Don't forget to look into protecting against [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and moving away from the deprecated MySQL API to use the [MySQLi API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: I've not aimed to make the CMS secure / hack proof just yet as I'm currently learning a lot of the basics of SQL and PHP, however I will bare all this in mind if I ever plan to use the CMS with any sites to go live.

Answer (score 0):

Using this method, you'll need a to make an edit page for each page.

**Main php file**

```
<?php $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","name");
foreach($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pages") as $row): ?>
    <a onclick="loadPage(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">
        <?php echo $row['page_title']; ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script>
   function loadPage(id){
      $.get('handler.php', { param: id })
         .done(function (loaded){
              document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = loaded;
         });
   }
</script>
```

**Handler php file**

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['param'])):
   foreach($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pages") as $row):
      catch($_GET['param']){
          case 1:
              require_once 'edit-data.php';
              break;
          case 2:
              require_once 'edit-data-two.php';
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
   endforeach; ?>
```

edit-data.php = edit the page X 
edit-data-two.php = edit the page Y